# Is it possible to have dynamic post id # in add_menu_page()?

Tags: posts, admin-menu, id, add-menu-page

I use the add_menu_page function in my custom theme builds but when I export my local copy of the site and import it in the production site some of post id numbers change and I have to update this function manually (ie: in the code below: ***?post=8, ?post=8, ?post=10***). Is there a way to have these numbers be dynamic?

```
function custom_admin_menu_links() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( ! $user->has_cap( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        add_menu_page( 'Home', 'Home', 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post=6&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-admin-home', 1);
        add_menu_page( 'About', 'About', 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post=8&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-id', 2);
        add_menu_page( 'Contact', 'Contact', 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post=10&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-phone', 3);
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_admin_menu_links' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [`get_page_by_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) that accepts a post title and returns the ID of that post. You might even use it in conjunction with [`get_edit_post_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_edit_post_link) by passing the ID and retrieve the edit link.

However, how can you be sure the post's title will never change? You could go a little further and add a settings page where you would map a particular post / page to an entity such as `HOME_ID`, `ABOUT_ID` etc. Then, instead of using the `get_page_by_title` you would just have this settings `array` and you could build those `add_menu_page` calls like this:

```
if ( ! $user->has_cap( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    $options = get_option( 'wt_menu_post_ids', array() );

    add_menu_page( 'Home', 'Home', 'edit_posts', get_edit_post_link( $options['HOME_ID'] ), '', 'dashicons-admin-home', 1);
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea. But it will probably take me a few days (I'm a PHP novice) to figure out how to do a custom settings page and the "entity" option but I won't have time for a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty answer would be something like this:

```
function custom_admin_menu_links() {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  if (  $user->has_cap( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    $type = 'book';

    $page = get_page_by_title('home','object',$type);
    if (!empty($page)) {
      add_menu_page( 'Home', 'Home', 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post='.$page->ID.'&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-admin-home', 1);
    }

    $page = get_page_by_title('About','object',$type);
    if (!empty($page)) {
      add_menu_page( 'About', 'About', 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post=8&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-id', 2);
    }

    $page = get_page_by_title('Contact','object',$type);
    if (!empty($page)) {
      add_menu_page( 'Contact', 'Contact', 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post=10&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-phone', 3);
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_admin_menu_links' );
```

But you are running a lot of queries on every admin page load. You really should work out a way to cache the results. Something like:

```
function cache_custom_admin_menu_links($post_ID, $post) {
  $links = get_option('my_menu_links');

  $keys = array(
    'home',
    'about',
    'contact'
  );

  if (in_array($post->post_name,$keys)) {
    $links[$post->post_name] = $post_ID;

    update_option('my_menu_links',$links);
  }
}
add_action('save_post','cache_custom_admin_menu_links',10,2);

function custom_admin_menu_links() {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();

  if (  $user->has_cap( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    $type = 'book';
    $links = get_option('my_menu_links');
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($links as $k=>$v) {
      add_menu_page( $k, ucfirst($k), 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post='.$v.'&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-phone', $i);
      $i++;
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_admin_menu_links' );
```

Then you just have to resave your posts rather than edit the code. I am sure even that could be automated if you needed it to be.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will give your caching code example a try but it looks quite complicated to understand for me.

Answer (score 0):

yes possible to make the post IDs dynamic in the `add_menu_page()` function. we can used `get_page_by_title()` function to fetch the post IDs based on post titles.

```
function custom_admin_menu_links() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( ! $user->has_cap( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        $home_post = get_page_by_title( 'Home' );
        $about_post = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
        $contact_post = get_page_by_title( 'Contact' );

        if ($home_post) {
            add_menu_page( 'Home', 'Home', 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post=' . $home_post->ID . '&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-admin-home', 1);
        }
        if ($about_post) {
            add_menu_page( 'About', 'About', 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post=' . $about_post->ID . '&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-id', 2);
        }
        if ($contact_post) {
            add_menu_page( 'Contact', 'Contact', 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post=' . $contact_post->ID . '&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-phone', 3);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_admin_menu_links' );
```